# Read only specific columns from text file in Python

Tags: python

Hi all I have few values in my text file as shown below

[image]

I Need to extract only first column that is "ColA". Is there a way to extract it.
Below is the code to extract all values

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('New Text Document.txt', sep = "|")
Out[7]: 
   ColA   ColB
0      3     F
1      6     G
```

Expected output

```
Out[7]: 
   ColA   
0      3  
1      6
```

Comment: (1) Show textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (2) You can delete columns from the dataframe afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `use_cols` parameter in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('New Text Document.txt', sep = "|", usecols = ['ColA'])
```

**Note**: Your text document is delimited by `" | "` and not `"|"`